# Breakpoint in shared object not working using lldb on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, lldb

I got a C++ project involving a shared object and I would like to debug it using lldb (tools interfacing lldb). My MWE consists of three source files where `test_lib.h./cc` only contain a function `add` and `main.cc` uses the `add` function`.

`test_lib.h`:

```cpp
int add(int a, int b);
```

`test_lib.cc`

```
#include "test_lib.h"

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

`main.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "test_lib.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a = 42;
    int b = 23;
    int result = add(a,b);

    std::cout << "42 + 23 = " << result << std::endl;
}
```

I compile everything using `clang++` with:

```bash
clang++ -std=c++17 -g -isysroot $(xcrun -show-sdk-path) -c main.cc -o main.o
clang++ -std=c++17 -g -isysroot $(xcrun -show-sdk-path) -c test_lib.cc -o test_lib.o
clang++ -std=c++17 -g -isysroot $(xcrun -show-sdk-path) -shared -fPIC test_lib.o -o test_lib.so
clang++ -isysroot $(xcrun -show-sdk-path) -o main main.o test_lib.so
```

Afterward, I would like to set a breakpoint using `lldb` in `test_lib.so`. With the following commands I can find a compile unit for `add` and I'm even able to set a breakpoint at `add`. However, `lldb` does not stop at `add` and continues to the end of the program.

```bash
lldb main
(lldb) image lookup -vn add
(lldb) breakpoint set --shlib test_lib.so --name add
(lldb) r
```

I also tried it under Ubuntu and here `lldb` works as expected.

**Edit** Added lldb session:

```
(lldb) target create "main"
Current executable set to '/Users/konze/lldb_test/main' (arm64).
(lldb) image lookup -vn add
1 match found in /usr/lib/dyld:
        Address: dyld[0x00000001800afdac] (dyld.__TEXT.__text + 52652)
        Summary: dyld`dyld4::RuntimeState::add(dyld4::Loader const*)
         Module: file = "/usr/lib/dyld", arch = "arm64e"
         Symbol: id = {0x00000150}, range = [0x00000001800afdac-0x00000001800afef4), name="dyld4::RuntimeState::add(dyld4::Loader const*)", mangled="_ZN5dyld412RuntimeState3addEPKNS_6LoaderE"

1 match found in test_lib.so:
        Address: test_lib.so[0x0000000000003f98] (test_lib.so.__TEXT.__text + 0)
        Summary: test_lib.so`add(int, int) at test_lib.cc:3
         Module: file = "test_lib.so", arch = "arm64"
    CompileUnit: id = {0x00000000}, file = "/Users/konze/lldb_test/test_lib.cc", language = "<not loaded>"
       Function: id = {0x100000032}, name = "add(int, int)", mangled = "_Z3addii", range = [0x0000000000003f98-0x0000000000003fb8)
       FuncType: id = {0x100000032}, byte-size = 0, decl = test_lib.cc:3, compiler_type = "int (int, int)"
         Blocks: id = {0x100000032}, range = [0x00003f98-0x00003fb8)
      LineEntry: [0x0000000000003f98-0x0000000000003fa4): /Users/konze/lldb_test/test_lib.cc:3
         Symbol: id = {0x00000005}, range = [0x0000000000003f98-0x0000000000003fb8), name="add(int, int)", mangled="_Z3addii"
       Variable: id = {0x10000004f}, name = "a", type = "int", location = DW_OP_fbreg +12, decl = test_lib.cc:3
       Variable: id = {0x10000005d}, name = "b", type = "int", location = DW_OP_fbreg +8, decl = test_lib.cc:3

1 match found in /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib:
        Address: libunwind.dylib[0x000000018bd54d38] (libunwind.dylib.__TEXT.__text + 8192)
        Summary: libunwind.dylib`libunwind::DwarfFDECache<libunwind::LocalAddressSpace>::add(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)
         Module: file = "/usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib", arch = "arm64e"
         Symbol: id = {0x0000000a}, range = [0x000000018bd54d38-0x000000018bd54e60), name="libunwind::DwarfFDECache<libunwind::LocalAddressSpace>::add(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)", mangled="_ZN9libunwind13DwarfFDECacheINS_17LocalAddressSpaceEE3addEmmmm"

2 matches found in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:
        Address: libobjc.A.dylib[0x00000001800604cc] (libobjc.A.dylib.__TEXT.__text + 9420)
        Summary: libobjc.A.dylib`objc::SafeRanges::add(unsigned long, unsigned long)
         Module: file = "/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib", arch = "arm64e"
         Symbol: id = {0x00000002}, range = [0x00000001800604cc-0x0000000180060584), name="objc::SafeRanges::add(unsigned long, unsigned long)", mangled="_ZN4objc10SafeRanges3addEmm"
        Address: libobjc.A.dylib[0x000000018008fb90] (libobjc.A.dylib.__TEXT.__text + 203664)
        Summary: libobjc.A.dylib`AutoreleasePoolPage::add(objc_object*)
         Module: file = "/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib", arch = "arm64e"
         Symbol: id = {0x000001ce}, range = [0x000000018008fb90-0x000000018008fc9c), name="AutoreleasePoolPage::add(objc_object*)", mangled="_ZN19AutoreleasePoolPage3addEP11objc_object"

(lldb) breakpoint set --shlib test_lib.so --name add
Breakpoint 1: where = test_lib.so`add(int, int) + 12 at test_lib.cc:4:12, address = 0x0000000000003fa4
(lldb) r
Process 22598 launched: '/Users/konze/lldb_test/main' (arm64)
42 + 23 = 65
Process 22598 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000)
```

**Edit (Solved):**
I installed clang+llvm 16.0.5 and now it works, before I used 14.0.6.

Comment: I think you need to pass `-g` to your link command too

Comment: Yeah, I added `-g` in link command, `r` command in lldb works fine.

Comment: Any reason you are not using an IDE like Xcode instead of doing the hard way through the command line?

Comment: Don't know about llbd, but a little trick to have a breakpoint when it's tricky is to add this in your add function: int volatile j=1;while(j){sleep(5)};, after you just have to attach to your program with your debugger

Comment: I can't reproduce this failure with either the most recent released Xcode tools (lldb version lldb-1403.0.17.67) or the most recent beta.  Can you put a complete lldb session with the failure in your description?

Comment: I also can't tell from your comment above whether adding `-g` to the link line fixes the problem with not hitting the breakpoint.  That would be surprising, I don't think you've ever had to pass `-g` to the linker on the Darwin tools.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I added `-g` to the linker command, sadly this didn't fix it.

Comment: @JimIngham I added my `lldb` session to the original post.